# Web service axis error on jena-arq maven dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, axis, jena

Every time i create a dynamic web project in eclipse (and then covert to maven) if i try to add jena-arq maven dependecy and then deploy the web service, eclipse says

```
IWAB0489E Error when deploying Web service to Axis runtime
axis-admin failed with  {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP (404)Not Found.
```

This only occur if i use jena-arq. Removing it (and also comment the code that require it) do not cause any issues.
Another strage thing is that if i create a maven project directly (so not moving from dynamic web project to a maven one) eclipse allow the creation of the web service but it will crash on an static variable assignment.

This assignment cause the web service crash.

```
Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
```

I googled it and people says that the problem may be caused by maven xerces lib that conflict with the xerces of the IDE. Any idea on how to solve my problem?

Comment: Apache Jena has a dependency on a specific version of Xerces (2.11). Other answer suggest you may be using Axis1.

Comment: Yes, i'm currently using Axis1, do i have to configure Axis2?